# Get error job doesn't exist in Oracle EXPDP

Tags: oracle, oracle-dump

I'm trying to duplicate a schema onto the same database. I thought the EXPDP and IMPDP would be the easiest way to do this it exports a schema from a database and imports it into another schema on the same database, it is exactly what I need.

But I'm some problems with it.

this is what I've done:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY exp_schema AS 'C:\DataPump\Schema Export';
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY exp_schema TO system;
```

this successfully creates the directory and grants the system user the needed privileges.

when I try to run the EXPDP function on the command line however:

```
expdp system/password schemas=system directory=exp_schema
dumpfile=schm.dmp logfile=schm_log.log
```

it fails with these errors:

```
ORA-31626: job does not exist
ORA-04063: package body "SYS.DBMS_INTERNAL_LOGSTDBY" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "SYS.DBMS_INTERNAL
LOGSTDBY"
```

I have no idea how to fix this. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is your database version?

Comment: @JSapkota version 12c

Comment: Try to compile that package `ALTER PROCEDURE SYS.DBMS_INTERNAL_LOGSTDBY COMPILE;` as sysdba.

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-04043: object DBMS_INTERNAL_LOGSTDBY does not exist

Comment: Are you connected as SYSDBA?

Comment: Yes i am connected as SYSDBA

Comment: Missing internal SYS packages suggests you have a problem with the database deployment. You may need to do some digging around to find what is missing. Alternatively you could just re-run catproc and catalog scripts/ [Find out more](http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/showthread.php?32869-Rerun-catalog-sql-and-catproc-sql). Depends what you're comfortable with, who else is using the database

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SYS.DBMS_INTERNAL_LOGSTDBY COMPILE;
ALTER PROCEDURE SYS.DBMS_LOGREP_UTIL COMPILE;
```

Cheers